# Equation to determine if a natural number is a prime, not a prime, summation or power of 2

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, divisibility, conic-sections

Thinking in a different way what $\ n = xy$ where $\ n, x$ and $\ y$ are natural numbers with $\ x$ and $\ y$ greater than 1 to represent non-prime numbers, I found that we can represent the multiples of $ \ x $ with $ \ sum_ {i = 0} ^ x + xy $ with $ \ y $ natural number

Using this multiple concept, a sieve can be created between two consecutive summations $\ sum_ {i = 0} ^ n$ and $\ sum_ {i = 0} ^ {m}$ where $\ m=n+1$  by subtracting 1,2,3 ... from $\ sum_ {i = 0} ^ {m}$ to $\ m-3$ steps marking the results.
The subtraction results are multiples, in the explained mode, of $ \ m-1, m-2, m-3 ..... $

When performing each subtraction, we have a multiple of $ \ m-1, m- 2, m-3 ..... $ and if the difference of $ \ m-1, m-2, m-3 ..... $ to $\ sum_ {i = 0} ^ {m}$ is greater than $ \ m-1, m-2, m-3 ..... $, we can add it and mark the results until we reach $ \ m-1, m-2, m-3 ..... $ or exceed that amount.

At the end of the procedure, the unmarked remaining numbers will be the prime numbers and the powers of 2.

If we make a graph for the equation $ \ n = sum_ {i = 0} ^ x + xy $, where $ \ n $ is the problem number, it corresponds to a hyperbola where considering only the positive whole roots it is found that:

1) Non-prime numbers have some positive integer roots greater than 2

2) Prime numbers have only positive integer roots $ \ x = 1 $ and $ \ x = 2 $

3) The summation has a root where $ \ y = 0 $

4) Powers of 2 have only positive integer root $ \ x = 1 $

Finally, with these criteria multiplicity, multiples of odd numbers behave like conventional multiples, for example multiples of 21 are also 7, instead multiples of even numbers are not always, so for example multiples of 8 are not of 4. No number x below their summation should not be considered multiples and in this system there are no multiples of 2.

Comment: I've read your post a couple of times, but I didn't see any question. Is there something specifically which you're asking us?

Comment: Is the described method superior to the sieve of Erasthostenes ? This sieve might not be the fastest, but it is the easiest method and already sufficiently efficient for most purposes. If you want to check very large numbers, there are other approaches anyway, like the Miller Rabin test.

Comment: distributive law and factoring out say a sum of multiples still a multiple ... not much new. it's really only y 1 or prime you need with your setup. But you haven't found any primes first.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I try to ask if it is possible to determine if a  number x is a prime number ignoring the prime numbers less than  x  and if the proposed sieve does.

Comment: @Peter I think that the proposed screening is not superior to that of Eratostenes in any aspect, but is different. Operationally it is less clear but allows to find prime numbers without having to know the previous ones. For large numbers it is not appropriate.